# Airflow - importing DAG with dependencies

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow

I deployed airflow on kubernetes using the official helm chart. I'm using KubernetesExecutor and git-sync.
I am using a seperate docker image for my webserver and my workers - each DAG gets its own docker image. I am running into DAG import errors at the airflow home page. E.g. if one of my DAGs is using `pandas` then I'll get

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/repo/dags/airflow_demo/ieso.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/repo/dags/project1/dag1.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas import read_parquet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I dont have `pandas` installed on the webserver or scheduler docker images, because if I understand it correctly you shouldn't install the individual dependencies on these. I am getting the same error when running `airflow dags list-import-errors` on the scheduler pod. I do have `pandas` installed on the worker pod, but it doesn't get run, because the DAG cannot be discovered through these errors.
How do I make airflow discover this DAG without installing `pandas` to either scheduler or webserver? I know installing it on both will fix this, however I am not interested in doing it this way.

Comment: _"I do have pandas installed on the worker pod"_   If the need for `pandas` occurs within a Python function that your DAG is going to run in, let's say, a Python operator, maybe you could move it from the top level into the function itself? Is that an option?

Comment: Is this best practice? I mean, it is definitely possible, but violating PEP8, so I am not too eager to implement this. I just feel like I am missing something when it comes to airflow dependencies, because I read you don't have to worry about webserver or scheduler at all, however if I dont install the dependencies on scheduler I cant even view my DAGs.

Comment: Well... HmmMMmm... Do you have a link to where it says that you don't have to worry about installing dependencies in the scheduler? Maybe my knowledge is outdated, but AFAIK, the scheduler is gonna continuously monitor and fill the dag bag (pretty much by "running" the .py files in the DAGs folder like regular Python files and then collect the DAG instances it finds in them). If your DAG definition imports a package that the scheduler's Python interpreter doesn't have, it will crash. Plus, PEP8 are _guidelines_ . There can be valid cases to break that standard, and this could very well be one.

Comment: I stand corrected, it appears you are right, my original assumption was wrong. I ran into this https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#best-practices-top-level-code and sure enough after moving the imports from top level, I got it working. If you want to post an answer I will gladly accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's great crafting an answer laid out by the OP's comments

In the comments, [@user430953](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5955479) provided [this link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.7.2/best-practices.html#top-level-python-code) to Airflow's documentation, where it states:

> One of the important factors impacting DAG loading time, that might be overlooked by Python developers is that top-level imports might take surprisingly a lot of time and they can generate a lot of overhead and this can be easily avoided by converting them to local imports inside Python callables for example.

This makes sense: The scheduler will monitor the Dag Folder and it will try to load instances of class DAG by executing the `.py` files it finds in the folder as if they were regular "importable" Python modules (erm... well... because they are) and then "fishing" entities (objects? instances?) of type `DAG` out the module's variables. That happens, more specifically, [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/c8b25cb3eea2bcdf951ed7c1d7d0a1f9f04db206/airflow/models/dagbag.py#L340-L343) and then [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/c8b25cb3eea2bcdf951ed7c1d7d0a1f9f04db206/airflow/models/dagbag.py#L426) (very broadly speaking and just if you're curious)

As with any regular Python module, the Python interpreter will "run" the code on import, so any top level import will be attempted. If the module imports a package that the scheduler's Python interpreter doesn't have, an `ImportError` will be thrown.

Since the OP stated...

> I do have pandas installed on the worker pod

... this means the actual work will be doable. We just need to avoid the scheduler from running this import.

The fastest way moving the `import` statement into the function itself, so the `pandas` module is only imported when the actual work is performed (unsurprisingly, in the *worker* machines... which do have Pandas installed)

So moving from:

```
import pandas as pd

with DAG(...) as dag:
    @task
    def some_pandas_work(**context):
        # ...
```

to...

```
with DAG(...) as dag:
    @task
    def some_pandas_work(**context):
        import pandas as pd
        # ...
```

... should do the trick